# SMTP won't send mail and after trying to send it gets added to queue

Tags: email, iis, vbscript, smtp, windows-server-2008-r2

We are having trouble sending a specific email to our Yahoo account using SMTP. When we drop it in the pickup or when we try and run our .vbs script, we are trying to send just 1 email to Yahoo and it seems that when we try to send the email using the pickup folder or .vbs mail, we don't get it to our Yahoo mail and it also adds it in the queue folder. So what do we need to do to fix it? Also, here is the setting for the IIS manager.

Enable logging is on with w3c extended log file in the general. In the access the authentication is anonymous access. The connection and relay is ok and the only list below is granted to 127.0.0.1.

The delivery in the outbound security is anonymous, the outbound connection is, ok the advance has a maximum hop count of 15 and the DNS is ok.

LDAP routing is unchecked.

That is my setting for the SMTP in the IIS manager 6. Also I try to send the email using the pickup and here is the code for the mail.txt but it doesn't seem to send.

```
From: blog@pdme.com
To: patrickjayson900@yahoo.com
Subject: Email test
This is an email test from your SMTP Server
```

This one is the code for the mail.vbs but it also doesn't seem to work either.

```
Dim sch, cdoConfig, cdoMessage
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
With cdoConfig.Fields
  .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 1 ' cdoSendUsingPort
  .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1"
  '.Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 25
  .update
End With
Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
With cdoMessage
Set .Configuration = cdoConfig
  .From = "blog@pdme.com"
  .To = "900@yahoo.com"
  .Subject = "Email test"
  .TextBody = "This is the test body of the email"
  .Send
End With
Set cdoMessage = Nothing
Set cdoConfig = Nothing
MsgBox "Email Sent"
```

Any solution or comment would be helpful and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mail is queued it means that your server accepted it for delivery, so your script is working just fine. If the mail still doesn't get delivered to the destination there are basically 2 possible causes:

- a configuration error on your server (you need to provide more information about your SMTP server configuration for troubleshooting that).
- the remote side doesn't accept the message (which should show in the logs).

Yahoo tends to be very picky about where they accept mail from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply also the problem was that some of the services that is running in the server was also using the port 25 and thus conflicting and not being able to start the website and the email sending

Answer (score 1):

use another pc because the ports that the mailer was using was also being used by another program in the server like the dns so the website that was working is now not working properly